# Unable to connect Oracle 11g via thin

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to Oracle 11g DB through my below java code, in an web application using Tomcat 4 server. ojdbc6.jar in Eclipse build path, but getting this below Error.

BUT when I tried this piece of same Java code in a Java file (public static void main()) and having ojdbc6.jar in Eclipse build path, it was able to connect to d DB, Very Strange!!
Then why this same code is not working in my web application??

**Server**: Tomacat 4
**JDK Version**: JDK 1.6

**Java Code**:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostName:portNum:SID","user", "pass");
```

Getting this below **Error**:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.r(C0)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.l(C0)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.c(C1)
    at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(O3LoginClientHelper)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.<init>(O3log.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:246)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:365)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide your Java code? Otherwise we won't be able to help you. I see that you have put `DB schema name` in your database URL - what are you putting there? It should be a database SID, not a schema name.

Comment: Do you have all of those Oracle jars in the Eclipse build path, or jut one of them?  ojdbc6.jar is the correct one to use - have you tried removing the other two and using just that one?  The TTC7Protocol stuff seems to be specific to ojdbc14.jar (so says [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/jdbc/ttc7/TTC7Protocol.html)), and it's not in the copies of ojdbc5.jar and ojdbc6.jar that I have.

Comment: I Updated the Question with some more info.Please take a look at it.  @PrzemyslawKruglej: I already provided the 2 lines of Java code, just want to connect the DB with loading driver. and yes, that's the DB SID Name.                                                         Luke: I have only ojdbc6.jar in my Eclipse build path. But still getting this issue. Code working on a standalone Java file with only ojdbc6.jar in path, but in the web application, there r other Jars like(spring,Apache commons jars etc.) along with ojdbc6.jar. May be some other jar causing the issue? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your standalone program is running correctly, it means your program runtime classpath is fine. However for Tomcat 4 its failing which raises a suspicion on the tomcat classpath. My guess is that since your tomcat is pretty old, it might be containing old driver class (may be *classes12.jar* or older ojdbc jar file in libraries of your tomcat (especially look into the  $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib). If that is the case remove all other jars except ojbdc6 from your classpath. Also make sure your web application libraries do not contain the classes12.jar or older ojdbc jars.

Also you can try to use **-verbose:class** in your tomcat jvm  startup to print the information from where the classes are loaded. This will however output lots of information in the log files.Search for the driver class and it will show you where this was loaded from.

```
Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from file: xxx.jar
```

Comment: Awesome, Removed ojdbc14.jar from tomcat path and added ojdbc6.jar and it worked. Thanks a lot, Shailendra.